# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - XCode simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

This problem came up overnight without me touching anything as far as I'm aware. Whenever I try to run ""react-native run-ios --simulator" using pods I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_YogaKit in libYogaKit.a(YGLayoutExtensions.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftDataDetection_$_YogaKit)
  "__swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider", referenced from:
      __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_YogaKit in libYogaKit.a(YGLayoutExtensions.o)
     (maybe you meant: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftFileProvider_$_YogaKit)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

My console as prints out a bunch of stuff similar to this:

```
/Users/me/Desktop/monorepo/client/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'RNImageCropPicker' from project 'Pods')
```

Any idea on what's causing the problem? I've been poking at it for a few hours and haven't been able to solve it. I'm currently using Xcode 13.0 .

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the Pods project in your workspace. Every pod you install has a different set version since you haven't specified the DEPLOYMENT_TARGET.

Cleanest way of doing this is to add below mentioned code into your cocoa podfile.

```
  platform :ios, '11.0' # Update this to set a minimum iOS DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
```